# Lines not showing up on Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization, subplot

I am trying to plot three lines on the same plot in Matplotlib. They are InvoicesThisYear, DisputesThisYear, and PercentThisYear (Which is Disputes/Invoices)

The original input is two columns of dates -- one for the date of a logged dispute and one for the date of a logged invoice.

I use the dates to count up the number of disputes and invoices per month during a certain year.

Then I try to graph it, but it comes up empty. I started with just trying to print PercentThisYear and InvoicesThisYear.

```
PercentThisYear = (DisputesFYThisYear/InvoicesFYThisYear).fillna(0.0)

#Percent_ThisYear.plot(kind = 'line')
#InvoicesFYThisYear.plot(kind = 'line')
plt.plot(PercentThisYear)


plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Percent')
plt.title('Customer Disputes')

# Remove the plot frame lines. They are unnecessary chartjunk.    
ax = plt.subplot(111)    
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False) 
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(InvoicesFYThisYear)

# Ensure that the axis ticks only show up on the bottom and left of the plot.    
# Ticks on the right and top of the plot are generally unnecessary chartjunk.    
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()    
#ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()    

# Limit the range of the plot to only where the data is.    
# Avoid unnecessary whitespace.   
datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
dstart = datetime.datetime(2015,4,1)
print datenow 
#plt.ylim(0, .14)    
plt.xlim(dstart, datenow)

firsts=[]
for i in range(dstart.month, datenow.month+1):
    firsts.append(datetime.datetime(2015,i,1))
plt.xticks(firsts)

plt.show()
```

This is the output... The date is all messed up and nothing prints. But the scaled on the axes look right. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the set up leading up to the graph if that is helpful

The Input looks like this:

```
InvoicesThisYear
Out[82]: 
7    7529
5    5511
6    4934
8    3552
dtype: int64


DisputesThisYear
Out[83]: 
2    211
1    98
7     54
4     43
3     32
6     29
5     21
8     8
dtype: int64

PercentThisYear
Out[84]: 
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4    0.000000
5    0.003810
6    0.005877
7    0.007172
8    0.002252
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib has no way of knowing which dates are associated with which data points. When you call `plot` with only one argument `y`, Matplotlib automatically assumes that the x-values are `range(len(y))`. You need to supply the dates as the first argument to `plot`. Assuming that InvoicesThisYear is a count of the number of invoices each month, starting at 1 and ending at 8, you could do something like

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
InvoicesFYThisYear = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 5511, 4934, 7529, 3552])
Disputes = pd.DataFrame([98, 211, 32, 43, 21, 29, 54, 8])
PercentThisYear = (Disputes / InvoicesFYThisYear)
datenow = datetime.date.today()
ax = plt.subplot(111)  
dates = [datetime.date(2015,i,1) for i in xrange(1, 9, 1)]
plt.plot(dates, PercentThisYear)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(dates, InvoicesFYThisYear)
dstart = datetime.datetime(2015,4,1)
plt.xlim(dstart, datenow)
plt.xticks(dates, dates)
plt.show()
```

If your data is in a Pandas series and the index is an integer representing the month, all you have to do is change the index to datetime objects instead. The `plot` method for pandas.Series will handle things automatically from there. Here's how you might do that:

```
Invoices = pd.Series((211, 98, 54, 43, 32, 29, 21, 8), index = (2, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8))
dates = [datetime.date(2015, month, 1) for month in Invoices.index]
Invoices.index = dates
Invoices.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of any way to plot using a Series, since my left column is linked with the counts on the right? Or maybe slicing the series to lists?

Comment: @jenryb, I've edited my answer to address the use of a series instead.

Comment: There is an open PR which adds the ability to extract the index from a `Series` object passed in.